# Magento Manage customer not working after upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento

After i upgraded the magento from 1.7 to 1.9,
I am not able to access manage customer section from admin dashboard.
I am getting following error.

> Gateway Time-out
>
> The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server
>   or application.

**Edit:**
If i clear the cache it works for the first time and then the issue will reappear if i try to access the manage customer section again.

Comment: I dont this this would be error due to upgrade. please check customization which you have done.

Answer (score 0):

check your installed extensions if you find any extension for manage customer then disable it and check after refresh cache.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally comes when one server waits for response from another server for too much time. But it could be anything. What I would suggest you to check the Mage_Customer module and if it is enable try to remove log of the website as it make website slow. For removing the log try this

login to shell(SSH) panel and go to your website root/shell folder.

execute the below command inside the shell folder

`php -f log.php clean`

Comment: Hi I tried it but it wont work. If i clear the cache then it works for the first time and wont work afterwards. I guess it has something to do with cache.